# How will remote api calls in PhoneGap app work with Good?

Tags: web-services, cordova, proxy

I want to use an existing developed PhoneGap app I have developed and deploy it onto [Good](http://au.good.com/).

What I don't understand is how authentication of remote api calls will work within Good?

### For example

- Within the app I make remote calls to a webservice end point
- The webservice is strictly only available to authenticated users' within
  the network (It's behind a firewall)

### Questions

1. Does Good provide a proxy, where the url of the webservice is pointed to the Good server which in turn calls the actual webservice end point?
2. If so, is the proxy 'automatically; created or does a proxy alias have to be created in good and it is this alias as what I specify within the phonegap app? i.e. Do I have to change the web service url in the PhoneGap app
3. Any ideas how fire-walled web services are configured in Good?
4. Is the authentication of the user passed through Good which effectively is setup to access resources within the fire-walled internal network?
5. Do I have to package the PhoneGap app into a 'Good' app?

Thanks

**Edit**
I have seen that '[Containerizing via App Wrapping](http://www1.good.com/secure-mobility-solution/mobile-application-containerization/wrapping-or-coding.html)' may come into this somewhere?